# 'Not element of' in Latin Modern

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode, unicode-math, latin-modern

In the following example, the ∉ symbol does not look good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
This does not show: $\notin$ \\
This does not look good: $\not\in$
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

`\not\in` works when not loading `unicode-math`, but `unicode-math` somehow prevents it from working (?). The Unicode character `0x2209` (`\notin`) does not seem to be included in the Latin Modern Math font. I know that I can load the Unicode character from another font, but I just want the output to look like `\not\in` in Computer Modern.

edit: To clarify, I just want the output to look like `\not\in` without using `unicode-math`. I want to use `unicode-math` for reasons not visible in this example.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

After last Khaled's comment, here's something that seems to work

```
\Umathchardef\xnot="3 \symoperators "0338
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\not[1]{#1\xnot}
  \renewcommand{\notin}{\not\in}
}
```

Then

```
$a\not\in b \notin c$
```

will work (although the placement doesn't seem to be optimal).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\Umathchardef\xnot="3 \symoperators "0338
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\not[1]{#1\xnot}
\renewcommand{\notin}{\in\xnot}}

\begin{document}

$a \not\in S_{\not\in}$

$a\in\xnot b \notin c$

$a\in b \in c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible improvement is to say

```
\Umathchardef\xnot="3 \symoperators "0338
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\not[1]{#1\mathrel{\mkern1mu}\xnot}
  \renewcommand{\notin}{\not\in}
}
```

that pushes the slash slightly to the right, so that the upper end is lined up with the terminators of the `\in` symbol.

[image]

Note: this definitely doesn't work with XITS Math or Asana Math, which, however, have the proper symbol.

### UPDATE

As of January 2013, the problem seems to be solved; here's the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

$a \not\in S_{\not\in}$

$a \notin S_{\notin}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX give the correct result.

### FURTHER UPDATES

The code was broken again, but version 0.8j of `unicode-math` seems to have fixed the issues.

Comment: I once considered something like that, but it does not look that good with XITS and Cambria, not sure if `unicode-math` should do that by default or not.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I guess not too; just a hack for the missing symbol in Latin Modern Math. I'm trying to fix the spacing.

Comment: This works perfectly and fixes my problem! Do you think you could briefly explain the `\Umathchardef` command? Google is not a big help. I suppose you use it to define a command (`\xnot`) to correspond to a Unicode character (`0x338`), but I don't know what the `"3` and `\symoperators` are for, or what the different options are here.

Comment: @Semafoor It's XeTeX and LuaTeX lingo for defining a relation symbol (`"3`), from math font `\symoperators` and position `"338`.

Comment: I'm using the latest TeXLive and I still get a difference between $\not\in$ and $\notin$ in the minimal example - in that the first looks bad (as does $\not\subset$ etc.). If I enter directly as Unicode, of course, they're fine.

Comment: @emacsomancer You're right: it seems that a recent update of `unicode-math` (or `fontspec`) broke the thing again. :( If I use TeX Live 2013, the output is the same as reported.

Comment: To get those fonts to TexLive 2015 in OSX, thread here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173141/13173 which is however outdated. I have not managed to get those fonts there yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\newcommand\cnot[1]{%
  \mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$#1$\hfil\cr\hfil$/$\hfil\cr}}}

\begin{document}

$a \cnot\in S$

\end{document}
```

Note: I don't know why Oberdiek's `centernot` package also fail. So I had to implement one myself.

---

Edit:

To make the macro to change size automatically as egreg suggested,

```
\def\cnot#1{\mathrel{\mathpalette\ccnot{#1}}}
\def\ccnot#1#2{\ooalign{\hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr\hfil$#1/$\hfil\cr}} % helper macro
```

Comment: It seems that `unicode-math`'s `\not` is really badly implemented, all my math fonts cannot typeset `\not\in` properly.

Comment: The reason is that `centernot` expects that `\not` has zero width.

Comment: @Leo Liu: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/xelatex-math-weirdness-misaligned-not

Comment: @egrep: `\not` is zero width in most Unicode fonts too, I think the problem is because it is defined as a math accent not a relation symbol in unicode-math.

Comment: @KhaledHosny The linked question doesn't help, as the `\notin` symbol is missing from Latin Modern Math. :( Why `\not` is a math accent is a mystery.

Comment: @LeoLiu Would you implement it with `\mathpalette` so that the symbol changes size in subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: @egreg: not so mysterious, it is a combining mark in Unicode, so that is the logical choice, it should then be handled by the engine (I had a patch for luatex, but had to hold it back because accents break math spacing rules, I'm yet to find a sane solution for this). But it makes little difference, defining it as mathrel does not help a bit, because of the way it is designed in all fonts, try `\Umathchardef\not="3 \symoperators "0338` yourself.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I tried: nothing was printed. :) What's wrong is that it actually *doesn't* combine!

Comment: @egreg, it prints here, but look closely, it will be shifted to the left away of the symbol. It doesn't combine because the engines don't handle it correctly, the old TeX approach doesn't work here because it was a CM specific Knuthian hack.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works perfectly. Combining it with 

`\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\not[1]{\cnot#1}
  \renewcommand{\notin}{\not\in}
}`

also doesn't require you to change your document's source code. I'm picking egreg's answer as the accepted one because it somehow seems 'cleaner' to me, and the output is identical.

Answer (score 2):

Try `\centernot\in` (from the `centernot` package): It centers the `/` above whatever symbol follows.