# How to add the MacTeX subpackage Latin-Modern-Fonts to a BasicTeX installation

Tags: mactex, latin-modern

I've installed the current BasicTeX, a subset of MacTeX 2013.  This includes the Latin Modern fonts, presumably in the TeX Live directory tree, which isn't a place that OSX looks for fonts.  The full MacTeX distribution has a subpackage called Latin-Modern-Fonts.  This is supposed to install Latin Modern as a normal OSX font, that all programs can use.  MacTeX also includes 2 GB of stuff I don't want.

My question: is it possible to install the union of BasicTeX and Latin-Modern-Fonts, ideally without downloading the full MacTeX distribution?  If not, is there a simple way to install the fonts by hand?

Comment: There is a TeX Live manager (TLMgr) that is certainly also in MacTeX. It allows you to install individual (groups of) packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! `cp -p /usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm*/* ~/Library/Fonts` or `/Library/Fonts` or alternative location if Mac OS X now keeps its fonts elsewhere. It may also work to copy the directory which would be neater `cp -pr /usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm* ~/Library/Fonts/`

Comment: Bernard, I found tlmgr, but I couldn't find the L-M-F package.  I assumed the 6 subpackages of MacTeX were "packages" in the TeXlive sense, instead of the OSX sense.  That could be wrong.

Comment: Good answer @cfr!  But I used `ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm '/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern'`

Comment: If it works... Maybe OS X applications are better behaved than they used to be! (You used to need the actual fonts somewhere under `.../Fonts/...`. But maybe that's no longer the case.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, without using the command line at all. Just download the [MacTeX Additions](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-additions.pkg) (that is MacTeX *without* TeX Live, soit 271 Mo) instead of the full MacTeX package (2 Go), and double-click on it. It will give you the choice of personalizing your installation. Here is the relevant window (in French, sorry — "personnaliser" for "personalize").

[image]

You may choose to install the Latin Modern OpenType fonts only:

[image]

Note that the full MacTeX installer also gives you that choice if you choose to personalize its installation, but of course it is far bigger to download.

You have the details of all possibilities of the MacTeX Additions here (where BasicTeX can also be downloaded): http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html

Comment: I opened a bounty on this because I think the pieces of information are outdated. The full package of MacTex-2015 does not have the Latin fonts. Any idea what is the standard way to get them then?

Comment: @Masi I suppose the most standard way is to download them at their "foundry": http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I opened a new thread about this here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205639/15504

Answer (score 2):

Latin Modern Math font is separated from MacTeX 2015, but the following works also in MacTeX 2013. 
You can find the font [here from the GUST project](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html) which you can install by

- extract the zip package
- open *fontbook*
- press plus symbol to add the font there
- select the font file in the folder where you unzipped the zip-archive

Extension of this thread to Mac is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205639/15504) in Ask Different.