# Not independent Sign in Latex

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I want to do the not independent sign in latex without having to install or define new commands (since I am using latexIT and I cannot load new packages).

Currently I use the following sign for independent:

```
X{\perp\!\!\!\perp}Y
```

What can I use for X not independent of Y?  I.e., something like this: [image]?

Comment: Related: [double perpendicular symbol (for independence)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79434/5764)

Comment: @Werner thanks, it looks ok but I'd like the diagonal line to go over the independence sign, is that impossible with the base latex system?

Answer (score 22):

Without packages/commands, here's one option:

[image]

```
$X \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$
```

You might be better off considering using the [`centernot` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot) for negating the symbol. And, if you can't load new packages, copy the required code like below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Taken from http://ctan.org/pkg/centernot
\newcommand*{\centernot}{%
  \mathpalette\@centernot
}
\def\@centernot#1#2{%
  \mathrel{%
    \rlap{%
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1{#2}$}%
      \kern.5\dimen@
      \settowidth\dimen@{$\m@th#1=$}%
      \kern-.5\dimen@
      $\m@th#1\not$%
    }%
    {#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\independent}{\perp\mkern-9.5mu\perp}
\newcommand{\notindependent}{\centernot{\independent}}

\begin{document}

$A \notindependent B^{C \notindependent D^{E \notindependent F}}$

$A \independent B^{C \independent D^{E \independent F}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `centernot` solution works well with `\Perp` from `txfonts`. I defined a custom command (n for negated): `\newcommand{\nPerp}{\centernot{\Perp}}`

Answer (score 11):

The symbol can be constructed using `\perp` and `\not`. The distance between the lines of the equals symbol is taken as distance between the vertical lines in the independent symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\indep}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette{\@indep}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\nindep}{%
  \mathbin{%                   % The final symbol is a binary math operator
    \mathpalette{\@indep}{\not}% \mathpalette helps for the adaptation
                               % of the symbol to the different math styles.
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@indep}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: empty or \not
  \sbox0{$#1\perp\m@th$}%        box 0 contains \perp symbol
  \sbox2{$#1=$}%                 box 2 for the height of =
  \sbox4{$#1\vcenter{}$}%        box 4 for the height of the math axis
  \rlap{\copy0}%                 first \perp
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht2-\ht4-.2pt\relax
      % The equals symbol is centered around the math axis.
      % The following equations are used to calculate the
      % right shift of the second \perp:
      % [1] ht(equals) - ht(math_axis) = line_width + 0.5 gap
      % [2] right_shift(second_perp) = line_width + gap
      % The line width is approximated by the default line width of 0.4pt
  \kern\dimen@
  {#2}%
      % {\not} in case of \nindep;
      % the braces convert the relational symbol \not to an ordinary
      % math object without additional horizontal spacing.
  \kern\dimen@
  \copy0 %                       second \perp
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \indep B \nindep C = D \]
\[ \scriptstyle A \indep B \nindep C = D \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle A \indep B \nindep C = D\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Version for `unicode-math`

`\not` does not work as expected, when package `unicode-math` is loaded. The following version uses the slash instead (the slope is slightly different).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\indep}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette{\@indep}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\nindep}{%
  \mathbin{%                   % The final symbol is a binary math operator
    %\mathpalette{\@indep}{\not}% \mathpalette helps for the adaptation
    \mathpalette{\@indep}{/}%
                               % of the symbol to the different math styles.
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@indep}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: empty or \not
  \sbox0{$#1\perp\m@th$}%        box 0 contains \perp symbol
  \sbox2{$#1=$}%                 box 2 for the height of =
  \sbox4{$#1\vcenter{}$}%        box 4 for the height of the math axis
  \rlap{\copy0}%                 first \perp
  \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht2-\ht4-.2pt\relax
      % The equals symbol is centered around the math axis.
      % The following equations are used to calculate the
      % right shift of the second \perp:
      % [1] ht(equals) - ht(math_axis) = line_width + 0.5 gap
      % [2] right_shift(second_perp) = line_width + gap
      % The line width is approximated by the default line width of 0.4pt
  \kern\dimen@
  \ifx\\#2\\%
  \else
    \hbox to \wd2{\hss$#1#2\m@th$\hss}%
    \kern-\wd2 %
  \fi
  \kern\dimen@
  \copy0 %                       second \perp
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \indep B \nindep C = D \]
\[ \scriptstyle A \indep B \nindep C = D \]
\[ \scriptscriptstyle A \indep B \nindep C = D\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result unicode-math]

Comment: When I try to use this solution naïvely (i.e., I haven't had time to figure out what's going on) I'm getting lots of complaints that I'm missing `{` and `}` when `\nindep` is used. Any thoughts as to why? edit: Just noticed that the errors aren't listing the same text as problematic: `./chapters/tutorial.tex:260: Missing { inserted. [$\nindep]
./chapters/tutorial.tex:260: Missing } inserted. [$\nindep$]` or `
./chapters/tutorial.tex:260: Missing { inserted. [\[\nindep]
./chapters/tutorial.tex:260: Missing } inserted. [\[\nindep\]]` (there are 4 of the first and 10 of the latter line),

Comment: @mpacer Generate a minimal example, which shows the problem. This can help you to find the cause of the problem. Otherwise the MWE can then be used in a followup question.

Comment: The only content in the line is $\nindep$, that's why I asked. I have a MWE working, but it doesn't work when embedded in a much larger set of documents that I cannot extract it from. I was hoping you would have some insight as to why the use of `\not` would expect to see `{` or `}` in a way that would break the code above, as the `\not` seems to be the culprit. Is there anything that modifies the definition of `\not` to require `{` and `}` that you know of off the top of your head? 
I've looked and am running into lots of dead ends…

Comment: @mpacer If you have an example, which does not show the problem, then it is not a MWE for this problem. Either strip down the larger document until the unnecessary parts are removed and the then simple document shows the problem or extend the small document until it shows the problem. Maybe a package (`unicode-math` or whatever) redefines command sequences (e.g., `\not`), needed by `\nindep`.

Comment: If I change the `{#2}` to `{#2{}}` the error goes away, but it just renders the not as a separate slash before the `\indep` sign, so it won't actually work. My guess is that somewhere a package is redefining not, but, which of many packages, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it's `unicode-math` – that suggestion was exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't think of any package that would redefine `\not` off the top of my head. So grazie mille; now to figure out how to fix it…

Comment: Ok…so after a bit of searching I found http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/xelatex-math-weirdness-misaligned-not and at this point, used the `\let\oldnot=\not` trick, and it only got weirder…I'll return to this later.

Comment: @mpacer I have updated the answer with a version for unicode-math.

Comment: Excellent — thank you. Was it easiest to just abandon trying to get `\not` to work when there was a valid option of using a forward slash? I wish I'd thought of that. Solves the issue for me, but I'm still curious about what was going on with `\not` because it was interestingly weird and I don't understand it. Particularly, when I used the `\let\oldnot=\not` trick, it vertically repeated the perp symbol in progressively smaller form, but details are better saved for their own question :).

Comment: @mpacer The documentation for `\not` in `unicode-math` starts with: `\not The situation of \not symbol is currently messy, ...` I had interpreted is as that the implementation of `\not` is not stable and the behavior of `\not` can change in future versions. This forbids the use of `\not` for non-standard cases like here, where it is used alone without direct symbol.